# Would reformatting the title bar help?

Tags: discussion

The current rendering of "*personal finance* & **MONEY**" may suggest to newcomers that the **MONEY** part isn't also intended to focus on the personal.

Yes, I know "**MONEY**" is intended to be a lighthearted jibe at how seriously we sometimes take the concept. But it throws the weight of the title into a less-well-defined space.

So:

Should we rename this discussion to just be "*personal finance*"?

Or should we change the presentation to make it clearer that we're talking about "**Personal** *Finance & Money*" ?

(Not necessarily recommending either as the ideal rendering, but the one we have doesn't reliably communicate what it's intended to.)

Comment: (BTW, I still can't log into the pf&M meta using Firefox, and have to switch to IE to post here.)

Comment: Just my opinion, but drive by users who take more info from the logo than the help page or tour aren't bound to be long term community members.

Comment: @keshlam I've never used anything but firefox on this site

Comment: @MrChrister: I don't think I've ever looked at either a help page or tour on StackExchange. And drive-by folks sometimes do decide to stay; that's certainly how I got here. More importantly: If we can make a trivial change that improves *our* experience by reducing the number offtopic questions that have to be cleaned up, I would call that a win.

Comment: @littleadv: Wish I knew what was different about my setup, but so far I can use FF to log into anything except this one discussion. When I click on "log in" here, I just get bounced back to the page I clicked it from -- as if I was already known -- but it still shows me as NOT logged in rather than changing that state. Some odd value of cookies, or some odd script dependency, or something...

Comment: Do you really think there's a major issue with newcomers  ' expectations? I think your suggestion would be great if the 'money' were a source of confusion for a larger number of new members, but, IMHO, it seems to be fewer than 1 in 20.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "major" 1 in 20 is a failure rate no business would accept. The benefit isn't large, granted, but the cost is trivial. Price/performance. I've had my say; you folks can decide whether you care enough to make the investment.

Comment: I agree that "money" seems to be a negative.  I can certainly recall cases where people were confused by it (or willfully interpreted it to mean they could ask economics questions), but I can't see any real benefit to it.  Is there a benefit?

Comment: Agreed, we could close this as a dupe of that. I still think the gain-to-pain ratio argues that we should really Do Something about this, but I'm not an admin so all I could do was raise the question (again).